# Search Data on datagrid view vb/access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagrid, vba

can someone provide help?
Trying to search data from data grid view using binding source

I'm using 2 text box with 2 different columns to search but only one can be search on at a time

```
    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    StudenName.Enabled = False
    StudentNo.Enabled = True
    StudenName.Text = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    StudenName.Enabled = True
    StudentNo.Enabled = False
    StudentNo.Text = Nothing
End Sub
```

and this where i need to input the search code

```
    Private Sub Search_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Search.Click
    If StuNo.Checked = True Then
        'search code

    Else
        'search code
    End If
End Sub
```

what i read in other thread is using binding source find and filter,

I'm Using visual studio 10 and access as databased

Comment: as long that a search sync on the data grid view its fine to me